# Xdebug 3.1.6 doesn't work with PHP 7.4.30 on Windows 10 with XAMPP

Tags: php, xdebug

I have Windows 10 with XAMPP, PHP 7.4.30 and Xdebug 3.1.6

The command `xdebug_info();` send to me this error:

```
[Step Debug] Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
```

I can't solve the problem.

Comment: What IDE / editor do you use (that you are using for debug)? Is it VS Code / PhpStorm or something else? I suggest you find some article/manual/video for your IDE and follow it from A to Z.

Comment: Regarding the error: it says that when Xdebug tries to connect to debug client (an IDE), there is no reply (or the connection is blocked by the firewall/internet security kind of app). Make sure that your IDE uses the correct port and actually listens for incoming debug connections.

Comment: Here are the official links if you are using PhpStorm: 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/debugging/ 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html

Comment: Where is your debugger listening? The default changed between versions 2 and 3. That said, with the little info you provided, it's impossible to answer. Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I solved. I had to put the password to my windows user.
Thank you very much.